# How to deploy custom Reusable Library in SAP BAS?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I have a custom SAP Reusable Library in SAP Business Application studio which I have migrated from SAP WebIDE. When I tried to deploy the same into ABAP repository through SAP BAS, it created around 2200 files in the `SE80` project which consists of mainly Resource file and MIME files. The same number of files got captured into Transport Request as well.

Folder Structure of Project:

[image: Folder Structure of Project]

`package.json`:

[image: package.json]

I tried deploying the custom Library similar like any other FIORI app using 'npm run deploy' command.

Comment: ok so it seems like it worked? it is deployed? where is the question?

Comment: @Marc: It is deployed but with additional 2200 resource and MIME files which looks incorrect.